# Parent entity is not included when child condition does not match

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework-6

I have a query where I have to return some entities with their children.

For the moment, if there is no children, the parent is not returned as well. What I want, is to have the **list of all parents**, and if there is any child, to have it included.

My Linq query is currently the following :

```
var query = (from parent in Context.Parents
            join child in Context.Children on child.ParentId.DefaultIfEmpty() equals parent.Id
            where child.SomeProperty == SomeValue
            select new {parent, child});

var result = query.ToList().Select(e => e.parent).Distinct().ToList();
```

Which generates the following SQL query

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ParentId] AS [ParentId], 
    [Join1].[ChildId] AS [ChildId], 
    [Join1].[SomeProperty] AS [SomeProperty], 
    FROM  [dbo].[Parent] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent2].[ChildId] AS [ChildId], 
                        [Extent2].[SomeProperty] AS [SomeProperty]
        FROM   ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Child] AS [Extent2] ON 1 = 1 ) AS [Join1] ON [Extent1].[ParentId] = [Join1].[ParentId]
    WHERE [Join1].[SomeProperty] = @p__linq__0
```

I have managed to create my SQL query that returns the results I would like, but I'm still not able to translate it in Linq

```
SELECT Distinct Parent.ParentID, fullData.ChildID 
    FROM Parent left outer join 
    (select Child.ParentId, Child.SomeProperty, Child.EmployeurSubsideID 
        from Child 
        Where Child.SomeProperty = 'SomeValue'  ) as fullData on Parent.ParentID = fullData.ParentID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classical `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with additional right side filter.

You have two options (both working):

(A) Apply the right side filter **before** the join:

```
var query = 
    from parent in Context.Parents
    join child in Context.Children
        .Where(child => child.SomeProperty == SomeValue)
    on parent.Id equals child.ParentId into children
    from child in children.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { parent, child };
```

(B) Use **composite key** for join:

```
var query = 
    from parent in Context.Parents
    join child in Context.Children on new { K1 = parent.Id, K2 = SomeValue }
    equals new { K1 = child.ParentId, K2 = child.SomeProperty } into children
    from child in children.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { parent, child };
```

Actually in **LINQ to Entities** you have a third option:

(C) Use `where` instead of a `join` (the pattern is recognized by the query translator and the generated SQL query still will use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`):

```
var query = 
    from parent in Context.Parents
    from child in Context.Children
        .Where(child => parent.Id == child.ParentId && child.SomeProperty == SomeValue)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { parent, child };
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that

```
var query = (from parent in Context.Parents
            join child in Context.Children on child.ParentId equals parent.Id
            into ch from c in ch.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where c == null || c.SomeProperty == SomeValue
            select new {parent, c});
```

Or

```
(from parent in Context.Parents
where parent.Children == null || parent.Children.Any(c=>c.SomeProperty == SomeValue)
select parent).Include("Children")
```

Assuming the foreign keys are set up properly, and note that the Property name to the children might be different.

Comment: For your second query : I have the feeling it wont filter the children at all. It will take all the children, but won't take all the parents that have children that do not match the condition

Comment: For your first query, if, I have the following error : "Cannot resolve symbol 'DefaultIfEmpty'

Comment: Fixed the syntax in the first query, in the 2nd one, if a parent does not have children, it'll be selected, or if any of the children matches the condition, the parent will be selected. That seemed like the condition you were going for.